# How to count consecutive number of 10 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with columns: id, name, date, present
Column present have values 0 or 1 or 2 and ... more
I need to count how many 0 valous is in current month 2013-07-01 - 2013-07-31 but count only when there are or more than 10 times.

for example if i have 
2013-07-01 to 2013-07-10 valoues 0 it should count it and let me know that is 10 or more consecutives days like 11, 12 or more, but if it was less than 10 should count nothing.

I was trying some examples from stack... but they are different problems... so i need little help with that mysql query.

i have smth like this but need consecutives 10 days like >= 10

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(name) as count FROM `table` WHERE (`present` = 0) AND (`date` BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31')");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $result = $row['count'];
}
```

It counts me every 0 values in date between 2013-07-01 and 2013-07-31 but i need count how many days start from 10 or more consecutives days

column present have 0 and other numbers like 1, 2, 3... so i need count only 0 with 10 or more consecutives days

here is SqlFiddle i was trying to make warking from answer
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bde8/2

best regards
m.

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses correlated subqueries to calculate two values.

The first value is the date of the previous record where `Present = 1`.  This allows you to get the number of days in a row where `Present = 0` by using `datediff()`.

The second is the `Present` value of tomorrow, which will be `NULL` on the last day of the month.  When today has `Present = 0` and tomorrow is either `1` or `NULL`, then we can use this record.  It is the end of a sequence of `0`s.

From there is it just a question of adding up the values according to the conditions that you set.  The following query assumes that you want to do this for each `name`:

```
select name, sum(case when datediff(date, lastPresentDate) >= 10
                      then datediff(date, lastPresentDate)
                 else 0 end) as DaysCounted
from (select t.*,
             (select coalesce(max(date), '2013-06-30')
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.present <> 0 and
                    t2.date <= t.date and
                    t2.date between '2013-07-01' and '2013-07-31'
             ) as lastPresentDate,
             (select t2.present
              from t t2
              where t2.name = t.name and
                    t2.date = adddate(t.date, 1)
              order by t2.date
              limit 1
             ) as TomorrowPresent
      from t
      where date between '2013-07-01' and '2013-07-31'
     ) t
where Present = 0 and (TomorrowPresent = 1 and TomorrowPresent is null)
group by name
```

Comment: as u can see i have query that counts me how many 0 values are in date between but i need implement 10 or more consecutives days

Comment: @user1805538 . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: i was testing that query and get "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: @user1805538 . . . If you set up a SQLFiddle, I'd be happy to test the query to be sure it works.

Comment: what i should get from this select?

Comment: @user1805538 . . . You should get the sum of days in the month of July where the consecutive number of not-present is greater than or equal to 10.

Comment: I need to count only 0 value in column "present"

Comment: column present have 0 and other numbers like 1, 2, 3... so i need count only 0 with 10 or more consecutives days. I cant use only 0 or 1, sorry.

Comment: @user1805538 . . . Let me repeat.  This counts only days where present = 0 and the number of 0's in a sequence is 10 or more.  That appears to be what your original question is asking for.

Comment: hello again, here is sqlfiddle where i test Your answer and get 0 record count where i have 3 rows with "preset" = 0. Here is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d828/4

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you a count only when it is 10 or greater than 10.

```
SELECT COUNT(`name`) as `count`
FROM `table`
WHERE (`present` = 0)
AND (`date` BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-07-31')
HAVING `count` >= 10;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: yup but i need consecutive 10 days

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but you could use user variables like this:-

```
SELECT SUM(if(ConsCounter=10, 1, 0))
FROM
(
    SELECT id, name, date, present, @Counter := IF(@PrevPresent = present AND present = 0, @Counter + 1, 0) AS ConsCounter, @PrevPresent = present
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, name, date, present
        FROM `table`
        ORDER BY date
    ) Sub1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @PrevPresent:=-99999, @Counter:=0) Sub2
) Sub4
```

Get all the records in date order and add a sequence number for the count since the present was first 0. Then count the number of times that counter is 10.